# Creating an HiddenFor() field for a object

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I am wondering how you can make it possible to do `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Object)` in a razor view? When I try it now I get an empty object back but when I do `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Object.property)` I will get the value for this property.

Comment: @Html.Hiddenfor can only be used to bind attribute, not object. How do you want to render the object? Do you want to display each field value of the object in razor view?

Comment: No, I created a step-by-step create flow and I want to have all the data in my viewmodel in the last step to create all the objects in the database but because previous properties are being deleted from the viewmodel when I send it to the view and back to the controller I have to keep the properties as an hidden input in the view.